# How do I create a document template in "Overleaf format"?

Tags: templates, overleaf

I'm the maintainer of a document class for PhD thesis in my old CS department, which I distribute with a template document you can start off from:

https://github.com/eyalroz/technion-iit-thesis

Someone has recently suggested to me that, for better accessibility to graduate students, I should consider publishing this template "in Overleaf format".

Now, I know overleaf.com is a website used for editing LaTeX documents online; and that it has a gallery of templates. But I haven't found a specification of a "template format" for Overleaf.

So, how do you bring a document (specifically, a template document around a class, with a bunch of files) into "Overleaf template format"?

Comment: Have you asked the support of overleaf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "template format". The instructions on https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates (bottom of page) say

> Upload or create templates for journals you submit to and theses and presentation templates for your institution. Just [create it as a project](https://www.overleaf.com/docs?template=paper) on Overleaf and use the publish menu. It's free! No sign-up required.

So just make a new project, upload the sample document and the necessary files (`.cls` file etc.), press the Share-button on the top, and then use the "publish" link:

[image: overleaf publish]

Comment: Oh, so you mean you never distribute "overleaf templates" and they only exist on their website?

Comment: @einpoklum Yes (I think. If I understand you correctly). As I understand it, an "Overleaf template" is nothing special, it's just a sample document uploaded to Overleaf and made available in their gallery as described above.

Comment: See also https://www.overleaf.com/help/77-can-i-create-my-own-latex-templates and https://www.overleaf.com/help/88-how-do-i-update-a-template-example-or-article-ive-published-in-the-overleaf-gallery

Comment: Overleaf tempalte is the wrong term. LaTeX tempalte available on Overleaf would be better.